# sympyでの３次元グラフ表示のアイデアを求めています

Tags: python, c, sympy

sympyについて質問です。結果としては画像のような図を出力したいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

用いる式は次のようなものです。

```
P = -A**2 + 2*A*D + 2*A*x*math.cos(phi_0) + 2*A*y*math.sin(phi_0) - B**2 + C**2 - D**2 - 2*D*x*math.cos(phi_0) - 2*D*y*math.sin(phi_0) - x**2 - y**2 - z**2
```

```
Q = -2*B*z
```

```
R = -2*A*B*math.cos(phi_0 - phi_02) + 2*B*D*math.cos(phi_0 - phi_02) + 2*B*x*math.cos(phi_02) + 2*B*y*math.sin(phi_02)
```

上の三式を代入する

```
theta_1 = -2*math.atan((Q + sqrt(-P**2 + Q**2 + R**2))/(P - R))
```

これらの式の中にあるA、B、C、D、phi_0、phi_02は定数であり、値が決まっています。

```
A=115、B=115、C=115、D=58
phi_0＝(2*%pi)/3*i (i=0、１、２)
phi_02＝(2*%pi)/3*i-(2*%pi)/3 (i=0、１、２)
```

iが設定してあることがわかると思います。
このiが0、1、2のそれぞれの時で計算し、その結果を合体させたいと思っています。

変数はx，y，zの３つです。

上の式で出力されるtheta_1という結果はｘｙｚの値によっては虚数になることがあります。 sqrtが使われているためです。

虚数になる場合はグラフに表示せず、theta_1が虚数にならない全てのxyzを画像のような図として出力したいです。

どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

プログラムの例やアイデアをいただきたいです。

Comment: こちらと同じですか？　https://teratail.com/questions/lx8ynkjha55off

Comment: おっしゃるとおり同じです。よければ何かアドバイスしただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: 現在の課題は「Sympyでの計算」なのか「3Dグラフの描画」なのかどちらなのでしょうか？「プログラムの例やアイデアをいただきたいです。」とのことですが、コードを見たところSympyを使用されていないようです。まずは解を求められてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: phi_0の式にある「*%」は何を表していますか？

Comment: `theta_1`の値は（実数であれば）どうでもよくて、結局`-P**2 + Q**2 + R**2`が負とならない`(x, y, z)`の集合を図示したいということで合っていますか？